# Python:Spawn enemy sprites at increasing rate (as to increase game difficulty)

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

[photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPlSn.png)[photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfvjt.png) I'm making a game using pygame where the user controls a player using the mouse. To shoot you left click. I need a way of creating a basic sprite and make it drop from the top of the screen **at an increasing rate**

I have tried doing this, but when I spawn a sprite in a loop, it just spawns so rapidly that the user would not have time to shoot all of them.

Have tried inserting a time.sleep function, but that just slows the game down completely.

Any ideas on how to go about this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: done. please follow link for photo of code ^^

Comment: Please post your code instead of sharing photos of it.

Comment: don't use screenshot with code - this code can't be edited.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with pygame, but I'm assuming there is some sort of game loop or tick that happens every frame. If that is the case, you could use a persistent variable to keep track of the next spawn time, and write an updateSpawn() method that spawns the sprite when it is ready. Something like this:

```
def updateSpawn():
    if currentTime > nextSpawnTime:
        # Make the spawn rate faster
        timeBetweenSpawns -= SPAWNRATE_SPEEDUP

        # Update the next spawn time
        nextSpawnTime = currentTime + timeBetweenSpawns

        # Spawn the sprite
        spawnSprite()
```